# How to get number of selected items in a listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a listbox:

```
self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                       selectmode='multiple',
                       height = 34,
                       width = 38)
self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)
```

I don't know how to get the number of selected items in the listbox?

In C#, it's:

```
listView1.SelectedItems.Count
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you're asking about the listbox in Tkinter as it is not a Python built-in.

```
curselection()
```

Returns a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element or elements, counting from 0. If nothing is selected, returns an empty tuple.

Comment: curselection() is equivalent of SelectedItems or SelectedItems.Count?

Comment: @popokatepetl, `curselection() = SelectedItems`, `len(curselection()) = SelectedItems.Count`

Comment: Thanks! @CommonSense

Comment: @popokatepetl, take a look [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) too. IMHO, [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) is most complete (from pythonist view, of course here a Tk/Tcl docs as well), most readable and newcomers-friendly. Good luck with tkinter!